# Writing readable LaTeX code for math formulas

Tags: math-mode, lyx, best-practices

Lets say I have the following LaTeX code

```
\subsection{Convex sets}
A set \( \mathcal{S} \)
in \( \mathbb{R}^n \)
is said to be convex if 
\[ \mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{x}_2 \in \mathcal{S} \implies \lambda \mathbf{x}_1 +
(1-\lambda) \mathbf{x}_2 \in \mathcal{S} \text{~~~for all~~~} 0 < \lambda < 1 \]
```

I find that even after formatting it like this with a new line after each inline math environment it gets pretty unreadable after a while.  I find that for texts that are full of math, in general, it is really hard to produce readable code.

Is there some best practices how to write more readable math in LaTeX?

I there something like LyX but with the possibility to write pure LaTeX and have commands being processed in the editor. Like if I write `\textbf{b}` then b would show as bold and the `\textbf{}` part would disappear. The when I hover with mouse over or place cursor behind b `\textbf{}` shows up again. Maybe this is possible with LyX?

Comment: [related?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40775/are-there-any-coding-style-guidelines-for-latex)

Comment: The link provided by @MarcvanDongen is good.  I would put a blank line after the heading, not break up the inline math, but on the other hand use plenty of line breaks and indents in the displaymath, splitting logical places such as the relation `\implies` and before the condition `\text{...}`.

Comment: I would as well use `\quad\text{for all}\quad` instead of `\text{~~~for all~~~}` and if you use it a lot, define `\newcommand\qtext[1]{\quad\text{#1}\quad}` and possibly `\newcommand\qqtext[1]{\qquad\text{#1}\qquad}` if you use larger space somewhere as well.

Comment: The title of this question is an oxymoron.

Comment: This is what LyX does by default. Go to math mode (e.g. ctrl+m and then type \textbf{ and you will see what happens)

Comment: This is why I use LyX - I see math, and I never have to worry about forgotten close brackets because I never get to see them. Incidentally, that does *not* liberate you from the responsibility of using semantic `\vec{.}` markup and redefining its style in the `LaTeX Preamble`, e.g. as boldmath.

Comment: What about Emacs with AUCTeX and preview?

Comment: Have you tried Vim LaTeX-suite? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96741/33287

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Most of what I say is covered by other answers, but I will write here my thoughts.

First of all, if you write a lot in LaTeX format, I think you should leave LyX and go for any plain text editor. In the (near) future you will be faster (reading and writing code).

About writing readable code. Here are some tips to make it readable:

- One of the main features I found in LaTeX is the ability you have to write what you want. But don't fail at deciding what you want! I mean, in your code you (shouldn't want) don't want `x` to be bold (`mathbf`), you must want `x` to be a vector (`\vec{x}`). You will decide later what a vector looks like, but at first, you don't have to worry about it.
- Next, if you usually define some sets you can define `\set` command (and later you will worry about how sets are displayed), but, as David Carlisle pointed, you can define shorter commands.
- This is a must have in my documents: `\R` (`\mathbb{R}`) to define the real numbers. It is an entity so I define a command to call them. But I wouldn't define `\Rn` for `\mathbb{R}^n`, because then you aren't writing what you want, you are  fastening your code input (which shouldn't be done that way).
- May be `\quad` is not easy readable for you, but I think it will in the future.
- This example is no so long, so you can't see how indenting your code benefits the reading of your code, but it really does.
- I use `\[`,`\]` but I don't use `\(` and `\)` because I don't read math really good between those delimiters. So I changed them to `$`.
- Personally, I don't write comments in my code unless I need to edit it later or something (I use comments as reminders). If you read code fast you don't need comments which explains what are you doing (in my case, they break my concentration).

This is how I would write your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\renewcommand\vec[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand\set[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}
\subsection{Convex sets}
A set $\set{S}$ in $\R^n$ is said to be convex if 
\[
    \vec{x}_1, \vec{x}_2 \in \set{S} \implies \lambda \vec{x}_1 + (1-\lambda) \vec{x}_2 \in \set{S} \quad \text{for all } 0 < \lambda < 1 
\]
\end{document}
```

After that, I think you should differentiate writing code and fastening your input. Most of people defines commands to write faster (like `\newcommand\vx{\vec x}` from Niel de Beaudrap). I don't agree with that. To write faster you should use an editor (or a third party app) which lets you create snippets (i.e. I would make a snippet with `\vec{x}` which would be called when you type `vx`).

At last, to fasten your code-reading you must use a program which shows your code with colors (a color for math, a color for commands, a color for text,…).
This is an example of my code (the theme and font I show here is not the usual, but I'm not in my main operating system, however I don't hate this setup):
[image]

### Summary

These are my ideas:

1. Write what you want (but don't misunderstand what you really want). The commands you use have to be *entities*, not just 'shortcuts'. Later, you will care about how will it look like.
2. Don't use commands as snippets (use a good editor or a third party app to make use of snippets).
3. Indent your code.
4. Use an editor which displays the code with different colors.
5. Again, if you want your code to be readable don't use `\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n` or `\vx \in \Rn`. I would go for `\vec{x} \in \R^n`.

Comment: What editor are you using?

Comment: I'm using TextMate (only works in Macintosh at this moment).

Comment: I know that this says a lot that has been said in the earlier answers. I accepted this one mainly because it points out that "you must want x to be a vector (\vec{x}). You will decide later what a vector looks like, but at first, you don't have to worry about it."

Comment: @Manuel What font are you using?

Comment: @Jörg In this image Monaco is used. But in my main computer I'm still undecided between Monaco, Menlo, Inconsolata and Anonymous Pro.

Comment: +1 except for advice about `$...$`.  I have switiched to `\(...\)` and find it easier to work with exactly becuase start and stop are different symbols.  See the discussion at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510/15925.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I think the only reason to like the difference between start and stop symbols is that you need it. If you use a good editor you know (with colors, shape,... ) what's inside math and what's outside, and then you don't (really) need to differentiate them. And, another example is `$(u,v)$` vs. `\((u,v)\)`. I lose myself in the second one. By the way, thank you for the comment, every one has his own preferences.

Comment: @AndrewSwann For *readability*, I like `$ <code> $` over `\( <code \)`. For *debugging*, the latter might be preferable. How a user optimizes (or even agrees with) these distinctions is up to the user . . .

Answer (score 26):

There probably are editors that do the kind of textual substitution that you describe (emacs on your example already makes the section heading in a different font, although it doesn't hide the `\subsection` markup, it clearly could given sufficient lisp definitions).

Perhaps I'm just an old Luddite but I find the font changes in the editor distracting and certainly if the editor starts hiding markup it seems simpler for simple things but for anything more complicated, or if things start to go wrong it makes things a lot harder to understand as you are never sure if what you are seeing is what is actually being processed.

What can help is to give more semantically relevant names to the markup so that it reads more naturally. Here I think you are using calligraphic to denote sets, blackboard bold to denote the common number fields, and upright bold (I prefer bold math italic myself) to denote vectors. so after some simple definitions such as

```
\newcommand\sets{\mathcal}
\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand\V{\mathbf}
```

You could have a perhaps more readable source

```
\subsection{Convex sets}
A set \( \sets{S} \)
in \( \R^n \)
is said to be convex if 
\[ \V{x}_1, \V{x}_2 \in \sets{S} \implies \lambda \V{x}_1 +
(1-\lambda) \V{x}_2 \in \sets{S} \text{~~~for all~~~} 0 < \lambda < 1 \]
```

Of course, there are many variants, if you don't have too many sets you could define `\S` to be `\mathcal{S}` and use `\S` instead of `\sets{S}` or whatever you find most natural.

Comment: The text would be a little bit more readable still if dollar syntax was used (e.g., `$\sets{S}$`), although there are reasons some prefer the Latex syntax (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to-dollar-signs-for-math-mode).

Comment: @CharlesStewart +1 I as well prefer the single-`$` syntax (not the double-`$$` one tho), especially with a proper syntax highlight it seems to be much clearer (even clearer than `\(...\)` with a proper highlight).

Comment: @tohecks - Right, the case of the $ syntax doesn't apply to the $$ syntax, which definitely should be avoided in Latex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- `\S` is the section sign; not good to redefine (and you'd be told that as soon as you tried `\newcommand\S{...}`).

Comment: Basically +1, but instead of your `\V` I'd agree with [Manuel's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86576/430) and use `\vec` instead, and `\renewcommand{\vec}{\mathbf}`. And since I'm lazy, it'd be `\vec x` instead of `\V{x}`, which is actually _faster_ to type on my German keyboard (`{,}` require a key combination, while space is the most trivial key to hit)

Answer (score 17):

In addition to Davids answer, you can use unicode with Luatex to make the code more readable. I know that this is difficult to input, and therefore not suitable for everyone, but I wanted to show what is possible:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Asana Math}

\newcommand\set{\mathcal}
\renewcommand\vec{\mathbf}

\begin{document}

A set \( \set{S} \) in \( ℝ^n \) is said to be convex if 
\[ \vec{x}_1, \vec{x}_2 ∈ \set{S} ⇒ λ \vec{x}_1 + (1-λ) \vec{x}_2 ∈ \set{S} 
    \text{~~~for all~~~} 0 < λ < 1 \]
\end{document}
```

Edit: As pointed out, the boldface x is U+1D431  and the calligraphic S is U+1D4aE . You can then leave out the command definitions, and write:

```
A set \(  \) in \( ℝ^n \) is said to be convex if 
\[ _1, _2 ∈  ⇒ λ _1 + (1-λ) _2 ∈  
    \text{~~~for all~~~} 0 < λ < 1 \]
```

Comment: Yes +1 you could complete the transformation by using U+1D431 (mathematical bold small x)  and U+1D4aE 

Comment: I'd argue that yours is a prime example of _bad_ practice because you hardcoded the style. For example, what if you want to change your `\mathcal{S}` to a different typeface? Do a global find-and-replace? Fine, but what if that also changes just changes the one `\mathcal{S}` that shouldn't have changed?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen It is not really hardcoded any more than $a + b + c$ hardcoded a choice of computer modern italic. In both cases the actual fonts can be set up elsewhere. It isn't always the right choice but it as advantages and disadvantages like any choice.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm not sure if you convinced me. As another example, with the approach of hardcoding you lose some basic sanity checks. For example, math should only be used inside a math environment. Also, where do you stop when using Unicode? Should you also hardcode the subscripts? Clearly not, because the size depends on the context. This is also related to hardcoding the `\mathcal{S}` because it's probably only right where one uses the normal type size. You can't just scale it for a subscript because there may be a special glyph for a subscript.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen (Remark: I'm not a fan of the "unicode-for-everything" approach) You can make the unicode char "subscript-2" `\active` (it is `\active` anyways) and then define it as `_{2}`.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I agree. The question here was concerned with the readability of the code, which is just one of the criteria for "good" code. One will always have to make compromises with each representation, and how you weigh each criterion is up to you. I just wanted to show the Unicode capabilities, not promote this as good practice. I think the first example is all right, the second was just taking it to the extreme.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen It all depends... Personally I'd rather my input was all ascii markup with the minimum of syntax highlighting. I prefer to see xml/html that way too. But I have learned that I'm in a minority, and the OP specifically asked to see less markup, and using a unicode based system is a reasonable approach to achieving that. It also helps if you are sharing expressions with non-Tex users eg Word more or implements the inline Unicode math described in http://www.unicode.org/notes/tn28/ which is rather close to the end result of using unicode for everything in xetex/luatex.

Comment: @tohecz In the inline Unicode Math described in Unicode TN28, the way to mark up subscript 1 is _1 so no active characters would be needed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, I forgot that the treatment of Unicode is different in pdfLaTeX and (Xe|Lua)LaTeX.

Comment: I don't mean to derail the conversation but is there a reason I see boxes rather than the formatted text in Google Chrome for this answer? http://i.imgur.com/QUdzD.png

Comment: @kush Who knows? I suggest you post it as a bug-report on [meta], that's the only way to find out who else is affected by that.

Comment: @kush -- i see boxes in firefox 9.0.1 on a windows 7 platform.

Comment: @barbarabeeton you do? You shouldn't see missing glyphs if you have stix installed (of all people in the world I'd have thought you'd have stix fonts:-) The issue in chrome is different, it has problems with plane 1 characters in some configurations.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- "of all people" indeed.  but i don't.  i mostly use the windows workstation only as an x-window entry point to several linux boxes and two vms systems, but the browser is on the windows system, and that's under control of the systems and operations department, who have outlawed addition of user-installed components, and are not delighted to be asked for "non-standard" installations; they reserve the right to swap a workstation in or out at any time, and prefer uniformity.  but your identification of stix fonts is useful.  (nobody else has.)

Answer (score 12):

I personally use emacs with AUCTeX and fold-mode. AUCTeX renders math, figures, and titles 
and shows them exactly as they will look like in the final document. All you need to do is the type C-c C-p C-d to generate all the images. When your caret moves to a generated images it is converted back to text so you can edit the LaTeX.

[image: emacs auctex]

This is what it looks like when editing a generated image with AUCTeX:

[image]

For things that AUCTeX doesn't handle, like plain text \emph{}, \cite{}, enumerate (and friends), and \ref{} (and others) I use fold-mode. fold-mode can work alone if you do not want to use AUCTeX for full rendering. When used without AUCTeX It will handle titles and footnotes (previously handled by AUCTeX) and will use unicode characters for math symbols; you can see the letter \lambda and \in in the screenshot.

[image: emacs fold-mode]

The "[c]" is a hidden citation, hidden by fold-mode, to see or edit it just move the caret to it. Same for "[f]" which is a hidden footnote by fold-mode, while with AUCTeX it is given its proper number "1" as displayed in the second image. The green italic "convex" is "\emph{convex}", rendered like this by fold-mode.

Comment: Sounds awful... I am accustomed to reading/writing LaTeX, and find "rendered" text distracting. Yes, it is the final result, but not what I'm writing.

Answer (score 11):

I do a *lot* of my early draft writing in LaTeX, so I place a substantial value in being able to quickly read my own LaTeX code.

As a result, I adopt a style which is half-way between the "LaTeX way" (of using the correct delimiters for math environments and semantic names for macros) and quick-and-dirty macro usage (to save not only on keystrokes made, but on characters to re-read). The following is a typical way that I would render your code-segment.

```
% In the pre-amble
% ====================

% A semantic command for vectors
\renewcommand\vec[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

% A syntactic command for special symbols which I would
% consistently use for a given purpose.
\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand\cS{\mathcal{S}}

% In the document body
% ====================

\subsection{Convex sets}

A set $\cS$ in $\R^n$ is said to be \emph{convex} if
\begin{align}
  \vec x_1, \vec x_2, \in \cS
  &\implies
  \lambda \vec x_1 + (1-\lambda) \vec x_2 \in \cS
  &
  \text{for all $0 < \lambda < 1$.}
\end{align}
```

I don't bother adding newlines in the middle of sentences, except for things such as footnotes and ends of lines (which is useful to do if you use a content revision system to track changes). But I add them liberally in my displayed math to better reveal the structure of what I'm writing, especially in tabulated environments such as `align`. You could also just use an `equation` environment instead, in which case I would write:

```
\begin{equation}
  \vec x_1, \vec x_2, \in \cS
  \implies
  \lambda \vec x_1 + (1-\lambda) \vec x_2 \in \cS
  \quad
  \text{for all $0 < \lambda < 1$.}
\end{equation}
```

Some further remarks on my approach to defining the macros:

- If you only have a few vectors in your text, you can make your mathematics somewhat more terse by defining

  ```
  \newcommand\vx{\vec x}
  ```

  to speed up your (or your collaborators') personal lexing process; how this affects one's ability to *parse* the mathematics is another matter. As with `\cS`, this sort of naming convention depends on the reader (most probably just you, but also any collaborators) becoming accustomed to parsing the name of the macro as an adjective-noun couplet: a "calligraphic S", a "vector x", and so on.
- As for `\R`, this sort of naming convention ought only to be used for a single style thoughout *all* of your documents for symbols representing very important objects (such as blackboard-bold symbols denoting number-sets which you are likely to refer to in any given paper).

Use such shortcuts with discretion, both for your own sanity and those of your colleagues who might also work on the document with you.

Answer (score 10):

One interesting option could be using Unicode symbols, e.g.  `∫` instead of `\int` and `ℝ` instead of `\mathbb{R}`, and use `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`.

There's the [neo keyboard layout](https://www.neo-layout.org/) (German site, sorry) which offers six layers (instead of the usual two switched via shift), one of which serves to input the most common mathematical symbols:

[image]
<sub>(source: [neo-layout.org](https://www.neo-layout.org/grafik/tastatur3d/hauptfeld/tastatur_neo_Ebene6.png))</sub>

The disadvantage is that the layout also remaps your Latin letters (it's an attempt to improve German typing, similar to Dvorak). But you can see this as an inspiration to modify your QWERTY (or whatever layout you prefer) to include this additional layer. (Sidenote: You can create Windows keyboard layouts with [MSKLC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/))

The neo-layout website also has [a German wiki article](https://git.neo-layout.org/neo/neo-layout/wiki/Neo%20f%C3%BCr%20Latex) on how to set this up with LaTeX or XeTeX, and they provide [the `uniinput` package](https://web.archive.org/web/20160814103631/http://wiki.neo-layout.org:80/browser/latex/Standard-LaTeX) for the mentioned `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` of probably all relevant unicode symbols (including e.g. greek letters).

**update** I figured out there actually is a Unicode block [Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols) including bold letters so you could write  instead of `\mathbf{x}`. Typing that could be implemented via a deadkey, e.g. <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> followed by <kbd>x</kbd>. So your example could be input as

```
\subsection{Convex sets}
A set \(  \)
in \( ℝⁿ \)
is said to be convex if 
\[ ₁, ₂ ∈  ⇒ λ ₁ +
(1-λ) ₂ \in  ∀ 0 < λ < 1 \]
```

which looks pretty readable to me. (I took the liberty of replacing your `for all` as well)

Comment: This will neither save you trouble after changing your mind to use `\mathcal` instead of `\mathbb` later on nor display `\textbf` conveniently though, you'll have to use e.g. LyX for that...

Comment: Do you know if there is something like this ready to be used with US-international as the first layer? (for GNU/Linux, or Ubuntu in particular)

Comment: @alfC Unfortunately not, maybe someone at http://unix.stackexchange.com does. But you can [download](http://wiki.neo-layout.org/wiki/Download) their Linux files or [browse the SVN repository](https://svn.neo-layout.org/linux/) to see how it's done and then adapt it yourself... (and then put a link here so others can benefit as well ;)

Comment: I opened a question in http://askubuntu.com/q/228050/15943

Comment: I tried but the code seems quite cryptic https://svn.neo-layout.org/linux/xmodmap/neo_de.xmodmap

Comment: It looks a bit difficult to read at first, maybe [the ArchLinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap) can help you there. Basically, you just need to [take the default xmodmap](http://david-mcneil.com/post/1424946010/create-default-xmodmap), add a modifier à la Mod 4 in [that neo_de.xmodmap](https://svn.neo-layout.org/linux/xmodmap/neo_de.xmodmap) and put the unicode characters to new columns. Or copy/paste the lines and fix the keycodes to match the US layout.

Comment: I'd actually like to have something like this as well, but I'm not settled on spending time on modifying a keyboard layout or learning that neo layout since it _may_ be faster anyway...

Comment: @alfC I just stumbled upon [this XKB layout editor](https://github.com/simos/keyboardlayouteditor#readme), maybe that helps somehow

Comment: @Glorifindel Thanks for fixing!

Answer (score 4):

As a extensive LaTeX user, who handles most of the texts under version control, I have found that it is useful to structure my writing so that editing is mostly shuffling lines around. Text editors have special commands for this, and it makes e.g. differences between versions (as given by the version control system) really show differences, not artifacts due to reflowing a paragraph after adding a word). Keep ideas together, go to a new line on all (most?) punctuation. Keeping article/adjectives/noun on a line makes the use of tools to check for correct usage easy ("a adjective" is easy to spot if on a line, if it spans lines it is hard to search for).

Mathematics is even more required to be readable (it is, in the end, a foreign, very dense and strict language), split into lines as warranted. Don't skimp on spaces in expressions (`\(x^2 - 2 p x + 1\)` is easier to read than `\(x^2-2px+1\)`).

Answer (score 1):

This answer got bumped to the front page again, so, an update.

I don’t actually do this, but as of 2020, `unicode-math` allows you to type in many Unicode symbols directly into your source, e.g.  (U+1D4AE) for `\mathcal{S}` and  (U+1D5EF) for `\mathbf{b}`.  If you use this style, you should load `\usepackage[math-style=literal]{unicode-math}`.