# Creating a custom macro for limits

Tags: macros

I'd like to experiment with making custom macros to see if I can find a way to structure things to efficiently take notes in class starting in January... as it is right now, there's a lot of typing to do repetitive things.

Is there a way I can define a `\newcommand{}` macro to do something like this?

`\l{x}{\infty}f(x)` would translate to `\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)`? I'd like to be able to just type as little as possible, and have the `\rightarrow` be automatically put into the typesetted document.

Comment: Personally, I think this shouldn't be written with a command. Related to what I wrote [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86504/writing-readable-latex). I would go for a snippet application which let you write `\lim_{ \to } ` easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\renewcommand\l[2]{\lim_{#1 \to #2}}
```

would seem to do what you ask?