# vim latex-suite: unwanted in-editor math symbol conversion

Tags: vim, vim-latex

I'm experiencing trouble using vim in combination with latex-suite. Since recently there is a nice feature, that converts some latex commands, such as `\varphi`, into symbols better readable and more appealing to the eye.

Whenever the cursor hovers over a line, this feature is disabled for that line, since it would bother typing tex stuff. You can see this in the screenshot below, where the cursor is on the bottom line.
However, when entering insert mode in vim, the feature gets enabled again, causing trouble with typing. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

[image: vim screenshot]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Wow, I reinstalled all vim-plugins, and now the 'conversion feature' is gone! I have no idea what's going on. Does anyone know what's normally responsible for the 'conversion feature'?

Comment: I have the same problem here, I don't even use latex-suite.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have encountered the same problem as the OP, and I found that it is caused by the neosnippet configuration, which contains the folloing lines:

```
" For snippet_complete marker.
if has('conceal')
  set conceallevel=2 concealcursor=i
endif
```

The neosnippet plugin probably uses the 'conceal' feature of vim for some of its autocompletion functions. The solution is either to comment out these lines or add an extra line in your ~/.vimrc:

```
let g:tex_conceal = ""
```

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160953/disable-latex-symbol-conversion-in-vim/18161073?noredirect=1#18161073).

Comment: Thank you for this information. I didn't know neosnippet had this feature. This clears up things.

Comment: Works for 'ultisnips` as well.