# Visual Latex Editor on Mac

Tags: mac, ide

I am looking for visual Latex editor (Something like Microsoft Word). Is there any helpful.

The reason why I am looking for one is that I am tied to a deadline and I don't have enough time to get adapted with scripting language of Latex.

Most of visual editors are not available under Mac OS (Based on this [List](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) ), Can anyone help finding one with double interfaces (Scripting and visual).

Comment: Do you mean something like [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/)?  (Not sure what OSes it runs on...)

Comment: yes LyX is good. Do you recommend it to write thesis ? or do you recommend other IDE ?

Comment: Emacs and Vim in my opinion are really the go to editors.  They are both available for Mac.

Comment: You mean (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides). Yes, I mentioned that on the post. I said that most of IDEs that support Visual editing don't work on Mac-OS

Comment: @user3378649: Your requirements are very specific and "you don't have enough time". As such, LyX may be your only option. Experienced users would not (never?) go with LyX, because the ease of control from pure code is just more comfortable.

Comment: @Werner: Thanks for your Comment ! if I need to spend some time on coding, what will be your recommendation (with helpful interface and shurtcuts: do you recommend TeXnicle,texpadapp . As first impression, Emacs and Vim are recommended, but they require to be experienced (it's like coding JS with notepad )

Comment: Something [related](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86504/writing-readable-latex). About readable code.

Comment: @user3378649: You're bound by your OS and I don't run on a Mac. I use Windows and therefore TeXnicCenter, which is sufficient for my needs.

Comment: OK I see TeXnicCenter doesn't work on Mac OS.

Comment: If you have a quick deadline, *and* if your university has strict thesis formatting deadlines (which may not be easy to satisfy in LyX), *and* it doesn't already have a working LaTeX thesis template, then you're in a tough situation.

Comment: yes, we don't have LaTeX thesis template. I don't have enough time to test all the IDEs, Can you please help selecting between  Texmaker Vs texstudio vs texshop or should I run VM-ware for this one texniccenter ? will be pleased to give hint. All what matter is an IDE where I don't stuck with strange errors coming from no-where (supported one).

Comment: As it is in one (mine) answer of the question I linked. If you are in Mac, you have the option of TextMate (which is very capable, I think). Also, if you have $70 to spend, you might want to look at Sublime Text.

Comment: I strongly suggest TeXstudio or Lyx and not spending money or learning to write in vim for this first "quick" thing where time seems to be of the essence.

Comment: Second for TeXStudio/TeXmaker. Good first editors for learning. Although at this point, given the impending deadline (which you should have thought about before now) you may be better off just not trying this right now. LaTeX needs time to sit and sink in; if you learn it on a deadline you will invariably come to hate a good thing.