# LaTeX as alternative to Scribus for large text books

Tags: text

I want to publish **multiple large text books**, each one **about 480 pages long**, this is print on demand (POD) on IngramSpark. The content is **basically text** and a few black and white images. Another important aspect is that the text is already written (it is a compilation). Currently most of the work is distributed in Word documents, Google Docs and Pages. What is missing now is to layout the text, review it and correct any errors.

I am not an expert in book design or layout, I am a software programmer and I have extensive knowledge of HTML, XML, Markdown and some programming languages.

I've already published a first book (not on IngramSpark). I wrote that book using Adobe InDesign. But it is commercial software, not profitable in my case because I am not exclusively dedicated to book design. That is why I started looking for **alternatives to InDesign**. The experience with the POD company was not good either, so I am deciding to publish on IngramSpark.

Another important aspect is that **I am currently migrating from Mac OSX to Linux**, so I started to looke for open source alternatives to InDesign. The first one I came across in my search was **Scribus**. I must say that in everything I read Scribus is a highly praised program in the free software community. But, in my search I read on several sites **complaints regarding long documents** (eg slowness in the program). The suggested solutions were not to my liking: separating the book into several documents (per chapter), trying to make sure that each chapter does not have more than 30 pages, and others … Then resorting to complicated processes to reassemble them all in one PDF. Other than that, there remains the task of making that PDF meet IngramSpark's requirements.

Actually, the editing work that I intend to undertake is great, **there are 15 books of 480 pages each**, so to think about having to divide that into separate documents per chapter and then recompose it again in a PDF and then have to configure it for IngramSpark … it scares me.

Looking for alternatives to Scribus I have read about LaTeX. I have no knowledge about LaTeX. But what I've seen so far appeals to me:

- has a certain resemblance to markdown, html, xml, things I know
- it would seem more powerful than Scribus (since it works, so to speak, directly in the source code of the document). I like that too, because I'm a programmer. In addition, this would give me the advantage of reviewing parts of my document in free moments, away from home, from my mobile or tablet, without having to be glued to the design program on the computer (as was the case with InDesign and it would be the Scribus case)
- it seems that it would be less complicated to work on large documents.
- the quality of the text seems great to me.

My big question, given all the above, is if **I can choose LaTeX to carry out this compilation** or if it is crazy and should I choose another type of alternative.

Has anyone had experience posting documents written in LaTeX on IngramSpark? In my research I read for example that CreateSpace (or KDP, I don't remember which one) prohibited documents written in LaTeX.

Comment: I expect this question will be closed as off topic, and I don’t know anything about IngramSpark. But for an example of a high-quality print-on-demand book produced using LaTeX, see the Homotopy Type Theory Book: https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/ . Its LaTeX source can all be found on GitHub: https://github.com/HoTT/book

Comment: Hundreds of pages of  basically text but "I have no knowledge about LaTeX,  but  I am a software programmer  and I have extensive knowledge of. Markdown" Then, no doubts: pandoc+R+RStudio+tinytex, and you are ready to use `bookdown`. Of course, it can produce a PDF book via LaTeX. The number of pages should be not a problem with a decent machine.  No idea of f IngramSpark, but if they can accept your PDF as is, then it  is irrelevant if it was done in LaTeX. If they want to edit the source,  be prepared to send all in Word (luckily,  bookdown projects can be exported also to .docx format)

Comment: @Fran, thanks for your recommendation. I didn't know about bookdown, I'm reading about it now and it seems like an interesting alternative to what I want to do.[Your answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419464/232968) it's a very interesting approach. Thanks!