# General Formatting Problems

Tags: formatting

I have started to learn LaTeX on my own, but as you will see the general formatting has lots of mistakes. I have tried my best but would really appreciate some help, here is the text:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\title{Lineare Algebra}
\author{Serie 1, Stefan G.}

\begin{document}

1.1 Gegeben sei A = 

$$\begin{pmatrix}
  5 & 3  \\
  0 & -4 \\
  \end{pmatrix}$$

Man soll A darstellen als Produkt zweier orthogonaler und einer diagonalen Matrix $\rightarrow$ Singul\"arwertzerlegung der Matrix A:

$$A = U \cdot \Sigma \cdot V^T = \begin{pmatrix} 5 & 3  \\  0 & -4 \\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}  \\  -\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} & -\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} \\ \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 2\sqrt{10} & 0 \\  0 & \sqrt{10} \\ \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \\  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \end{pmatrix} $$

Weiter soll man die Operator 2-Norm, die Frobeniusnorm, sowie den Spektralradius von A und
$A^{-1}$ bestimmen. 
Die Operator 2-Norm berechnet sich mit $\sqrt{\lambda_{max}A^H*A}$ wobei $\lambda_{max}$ der maximale Eigenwert der Matrix ist und "H" in der Potenz für hermitesch bzw. im reellen Fall transponierte Matrix steht.
\"Uber die Berechnung des charakteristischen Polynomes von $A^H*A$ = 

$$\begin{pmatrix}
  34 & -12  \\
  -6 & 8 \\
  \end{pmatrix}$$

erh\"alt man für die 2-Norm $\sqrt{40}$. Die Frobeniusnorm berechnet sich aus aus der Wurzel der Summe aller quadrierten Einträge der Matrix und betr\"agt hier $\sqrt{50}$.
Für die Spektralradien berechnet man die Absolutbeträge der grössten Eigenwerte. 
Berechnung für A: Das charakteristische Polynom ist $\Chi(A) = (5-\lambda_1)(-4-\lambda_2)$ und damit
der grösste Betrag eines Eigenwertes und somit auch der Spektralradius = 5.

Die Inverse von A kann man mit dem Gauss-Algorithmus berechnen und erh\"alt $A^-1$ = 

$$\begin{pmatrix}
  5 & 3  \\
  0 & -4 \\
  \end{pmatrix}$$
Damit ist der Spektralradius von $A^-1 = \frac{1}{4}$.

Wo ist denn Proposition 0.50 im Skript? Nicht gesehen.

1.2. Gegeben seien  A = $\begin{pmatrix}
  0.005 & 1  \\
  1 & 1 \\
  \end{pmatrix}$
und der Vektor b = $\begin{pmatrix} 0.5 \\1  \end{pmatrix} $

Berechnen soll man f\"ur Ax = b den L\"osungsvektor x i) mit dem Gaussalgorithmus ii) in F(10,3,-10,10) ohne Pivotisierung und  iii) in F(10,3,-10,10) mit Pivotisierung.

i) Mit dem Gaussalgorithmus erh\"alt man für den L\"osungsvektor Folgendes:

$$\begin {pmatrix} 0.005&1&0.5\\1&1&1 \end {pmatrix}\to \begin {pmatrix} 0.005&1&0.5\\0&-199&-99 \end {pmatrix}\to \begin {pmatrix} 1&200&100\\0&1&\frac{99}{199} \end {pmatrix} \to\begin {pmatrix} 1&0&100-200\cdot \frac {99}{199}\\0&1&\frac{99}{199} \end {pmatrix}=\begin {pmatrix} 1&0&\frac {100}{199}\\0&1&\frac{99}{199} \end {pmatrix}$$

ii) Ohne ausf\"uhrlich den Rechenweg nochmals aufzuschreiben, welcher gleich ist wie bei i) ausser dass man nach pr\"ziser Berechnung auf die festgelegte Pr\"zision rundet erhalte ich f\"ur $x_1 = 0.497 $ und f\"ur $x_2 = 0.6 $

iii) Mit Pivotisierung erhalte ich $x_1 = 0.497$ and $x_2 = 0.503$.
Wohl weil 0.005 nicht mehr in der Diagonalen ist (und Runden wohl i.A. nicht assoziativ ist).


1.3 Zu beweisen:

a) $ \|A\|_2 \leq \|A\|_F \leq \sqrt{\operatorname{rank}(A)}\|A\|_2 $

b) $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\|A\|_\infty \leq \|A\|_2 \leq \sqrt{m}\|A\|_\infty  $

c) $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\|A\|_1 \leq \|A\|_2 \leq \sqrt{n}\|A\|_1  $


Zu a):Beide Normen sind invariant wenn  $\mathbf A$ mit einer unit\"aren Matrix multipliziert wird. Man kann also die Singul\"arwertzerlegung berechnen, anschliessend die unit\"aren Matrizen streichen und die Diagonalmatrizen beibehalten. Für eine gegebene Spektralnorm, ist die kleinste Frobenius Norm wenn nur ein einzelner Singul\"arwert diesen Wert und alle anderen Null sind, und die gr\"osste Norm wird erreicht wenn  alle Singul\"arwerte diesen Wert haben; also

$$\|\mathbf A\|_2 \leq \|\mathbf A \|_{\mathrm F} \leq \sqrt d\,\|\mathbf A\|_2\;,$$

also, $A=1$ and $B=\sqrt d$.

F\"ur b) und c) kann man von den entsprechenden Vektornormen Gebrauch machen, insbesondere gilt . Zusammen mit der Definition der Normen ergeben sich dann die \"Aquivalenzen. Insbesondere gilt zum Beispiel dass $ \|x\|_\infty \leq \|x\|_2 \leq \sqrt{n}\|x\|_\infty  $. Zusammen mit $\|A\|_2 = max \|Ax\|_2$ und $\|A\|_\infty = \max \sum |a_{ij}|$


1.4 Nicht gel\"ost 


1.5
Was soll man denn hier genau machen? Die analytische, i.e. geschlossene Form ist ja bereits gegeben mit der Rekursionsformel:

$$x^{n+1} = x^{n} - \frac{f(x^n)}{f'(x^{n})}$$

wobei man den angegebenen Startwert f\"ur x^0 einsetzen kann und die Ableitung der Funktion nat\"urlich
einfach x^4 - 2x^2 + 1 ist.

Einzige Nullstelle in $\mathbb R$ ist x = 0 wegen 
$$\frac{1}{5} x^5 - \frac{2}{3} x^3 + x= x( \frac{1}{5} x^4 - \frac{2}{3} x^2 +1) $$.
Ein paar Werte ausgerechnet: es sieht aus als w\"urde die Funktion oszillieren mit $x_0,-x_0,x_0..$ wegen des speziellen Startwertes.


F\"ur den zweiten Teil siehe bitte Matlab-Skript.




\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi, the code is compilable and starts with \documentclass .. and also ends with \end{document}. I just did not find the right way to distinguish between question and code format wise here

Comment: @Stefan89 Are you requesting coding advices on how to format `TeX` code or? Furthermore, you can indent the code segment by `4 spaces` which will make it a code, you can also mark the text and press the `{}` button which will automatically insert the 4 spaces.

Comment: For equations you should definitely read: [Why double dollar signs are not the way to go](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)

Comment: Sorry, for sounding so stupid, but where is the {} button? And yes, I am asking for advice on how to format my Tex text posted above.

Comment: Please read through the links posted by @Jubobs, they are relevant for getting the optimal answers.

Comment: I read it but replacing the $$ did not help so far much..but I can continue reading..it is just that concrete advices sometimes help more than lots of reading

Comment: It was the links posted by @Jubobs, not the link I posted. Furthermore, your question is more about the coding style idiom of `TeX`, please see  [Coding guide-lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40775/are-there-any-coding-style-guidelines-for-latex). Also you should read up on the use of `\chapter`, `\section` and `\subsection` macros. The problem with your question is that it is probably too localized, meaning that it has little relevance to any others. I hope you return after having read a little more. :)

Comment: You might also want to have a look at my [list of common error messages](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/commonerrors.html) if you encounter any more problems.

Comment: You have a lot of expressions of the form `\| A \|` (matrix norms). To improve both the legibility of your code and the typesetting, I'd recommend setting up a dedicated macro -- e.g., `\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}` -- and then using `\norm{A}`. You'll find that (i) the subscripts (`2`, `F`, `\infty`) will be typeset much better and (ii) that there will some whitespace around the terms, which will facilitate the readability of the expressions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are (only) the problems I found which prevent your document from completing:

- After `\usepackage{amsmath}` I added `\usepackage{amssymb}` to allow for things like `\mathbb`. I'm not an expert here, so there may be other, better, fixes.
- `\Chi` is not a command, since many Greek majuscules are equivalent to their  Latin fellows. I solved this with `\newcommand{\Chi}{X}`; @azetina recommends, quite correctly, a better alternative: `\DeclareMathOperator{\Chi}{X}` (My only excuse is that I wasn't reading the context.)
- Missing `\begin{document}` (already edited in by lockstep)
- You have a couple of inline maths expressions where you have forgotten the opening and closing $-signs:

```
wobei man den angegebenen Startwert f\"ur $x^0$ 
einsetzen kann und die Ableitung der Funktion nat\"urlich
einfach $x^4 - 2x^2 + 1$ ist.
```

In my opinion, there are many other problems as well, but fixing the ones given here will help you to get started and ask other questions about the problems you will see in the output.

Welcome to the wonderful, but sometimes mysterious, world of TeX.

Comment: I recommend using `\DeclareMathOperator{\Chi}{X}` instead of `\newcommand{\Chi}{X}`.

Comment: You're very welcome. For your future questions, you'll be much better served here if you can post the smallest possible example that shows the thing you're trying to fix.