# Using '%' at end of line

Tags: code

When browsing though LaTeX source code, I have noticed that many people put `%` at the end of a line or after closing brackets. I would like to know if there is any benefit in this practice.

Moreover, I find difficulty in finding advice on LaTeX coding style. When I say style I mean LaTeX source and not the compiled document. For me the code it self is kind of an art as well so if there are any tips are welcome.

Comment: See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453), [Why the end-of-line `%` in macro definitions?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40946) and [Where are the necessary places to be appended with `%` to remove unwanted spaces?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19922)

Comment: On the 'bonus' part, see for example [Are there any coding style guidelines for LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40775/are-there-any-coding-style-guidelines-for-latex)

Comment: Ok, I guess this can safely be closed as a duplicate I could not find all these answers readily using the search... Thanks a lot.

Comment: @VagelisBebelis No problem: the 'regulars' know what they are looking for :-)