# Comments on my code

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm starting to use TiKz to create graphics and I would like the opinion of some more advanced users to comment on my code. Anything from tips to advices or things that could be done in a different and better way will be apreciated.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{float}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}



\newcommand{\subb}[1]{_{\mathrm{#1}}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw
            (0,0) to[battery,l_=$V\subb{in}$] ++(0,-4) coordinate (v)
    %       (0,0) to[short]++(1,0)
            (0,0) to[inductor, l^=$L$,-*,v_=$v\subb L$,i=$i\subb L$] ++(3,0) coordinate (s1)
            ([xshift=15pt, yshift=-15pt]s1) coordinate (son) 
            (son) to[short,o-] (son|-v)
            to[short] (v)
            ([xshift=22pt]s1) coordinate (soff)
            (soff) to[short,o-*]++(2,0) coordinate (c)
            to[C,l_=$C$,i>_=$i\subb C$]  (c|-v) coordinate (cc)
            to[short,*-*] (cc-|son)
            (c) to[short] ++ (2,0) coordinate (l)
            to[R,l_=$R\subb L$,v^=$V\subb{out}$,i>_=$i\subb{out}$] (l|-cc)
            to[short] (cc);
            \draw [very thick] (s1)--++(19pt,-8pt);
            \node[anchor = north east] at (son) {$T\subb{ON}$};
            \node[anchor = south] at (soff) {$T\subb{OFF}$};
        \end{circuitikz}
        \caption{Boost converter}
        \label{circ:boost_diagrama}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\ton{1}
        \def\toff{2}
        \def\von{2}
        \def\voff{-3}
        \def\ilmax{3}
        \def\ilmin{1.4}

        \begin{axis}
        [
            xlabel = $t$,
            axis x line=center,
            axis y line=center,
            x label style = {anchor=north},
            y label style = {anchor=east},
            no markers,
            xmin = -0.3, xmax = \toff + 0.7,
            ymin = \voff - 0.5, ymax = \von + 2,
            xtick = {0,\ton,\toff},
            xticklabels = {0,{$T\subb{ON}$},{$T\subb{OFF}$}},
            x tick label style = {anchor=north east},
            ytick = {\von,\voff,\ilmax,\ilmin},
            yticklabels = {{\color{blue}$V\subb{in}$},{\color{blue}$V\subb{in}-V\subb{out}$},{\color{red}$I\subb{L\subb{max}}$},{\color{red}$I\subb{L\subb{max}}$}}
        ]
            \addplot [blue, thick] coordinates 
            {
                (0,\von)
                (\ton,\von)
                (\ton,\voff)
                (\toff,\voff)
                (\toff,\von)
                (\toff+0.5,\von)
            };
            \draw [dashed] (axis cs:\ton, \voff) -- (axis cs:0, \voff);
            \addplot [red, thick] coordinates 
            {
                (0,\ilmin)
                (\ton,\ilmax)
                (\toff,\ilmin)
                (\toff+0.5,{\ilmin+(\ilmax-\ilmin)*0.5})
            };
            \draw [dashed] (axis cs:\ton,\ilmax) -- (axis cs:0, \ilmax);
            \draw [dashed] (axis cs:\toff,\ilmin) -- (axis cs:0, \ilmin);
            \legend{$v\subb L$,$i\subb L$}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Voltage and current in across the inductor}
        \label{graf:tensio_corrent_L}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And my result:
[image]

As you can see the resoolt looks fine but I would like to receive some comments about my code.

Thanks!

Comment: In my humble opinion, that's pretty OK code. Anything above this would be code golfing and subtle tricks. I think you quite nailed the standard. Maybe a super nitpicking is that pgfplots already loads tikz so you don't need to add again. I usually just load `pgfplotstable`which loads pgfplots, tikz and tikz also loads graphicx and so on which reduces the clutter in my preamble. It's not always the best idea (packages might clash due to option differences) but most of the cases there are no problems.

Comment: I agree with percusse, the code looks fine. To save some more keystrokes: Since you are a `compat` level higher than `1.11` you don't need to precede the TikZ coordinates by `axis cs:`. Thus, e.g. `\draw [dashed] (\ton, \voff) -- (0, \voff);` would yield the same result as with `axis cs:`.

Comment: Thanks @StefanPinnow, can `axis cs:` be removed from anywhere? Or is there some place where its still mandatory?

Comment: Yes, you can remove it everywhere (when you use `compat=1.11` or higher). Then `axis cs:` is the default used coordinate system (inside `axis` environments and the like).

Comment: I am voting to close this question, because no clear answer can be given. You can see some information on how to write good code here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40775/are-there-any-coding-style-guidelines-for-latex?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Comment: On closing these types of questions see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6382/2693