# "Standardizing" LaTeX code?

Tags: formatting, auctex, syntax, syntax-checker

Is there a program for LaTeX code akin to [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) that "standardizes" or "canonically" formats (automatically indents, spaces, etc.) LaTeX code?

AucTex formats code, but it doesn't appear to create a unique output for syntactically equivalent input.

thanks

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is **no**.

Comment: @Marco: AucTeX might be my best and only option, then. Looking around on other questions, it seems there is no standard LaTeX formatting conventions like there are for HTML and other code.

Comment: This might be one of those cases where you are better off describing what your overall goal is, rather than what tool you think will help you accomplish that goal.  For example, to decide if two LaTeX source files are equivalent you could compile to .dvi and compare the .dvi's.  But maybe that's not what you want to do.

Comment: AUCTeX does an amazing job, but it is impossible for it to be perfect without parsing the meaning of every little thing the user has done.  If you want to get a 'standardized' output based on 'syntactically equivalent input', run `latex` on the file(s). `;)`

Comment: Related: [What are the standard styles to format LaTeX source code?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24471/5245)

Comment: Maybe also related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100/86

Comment: Yes, `latexindent.pl`, soon to be available in `texlive`: [LaTeX code sniffer and/or beautifier?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26102); youtube demonstration here: [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_AMmNVg5WM](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_AMmNVg5WM)

Comment: To indent the whole buffer: `C-x h M-C-\ `.

Comment: @giordano: That's LaTeX-specific? It's very slow for my hundreds of pages document… (Actually, AUCTeX formatting is slow for huge documents, too…)

Comment: @cmhughes: How does that differ from AUCTeX's formatting?

Comment: @Geremia I don't have any familiarity with `AUCTeX`, so can not compare the two. Can you customize the indentation of every environment and command with `AUCTeX`? Does it know about `verbatim` environments, including your own custom names? Does it format environments that have alignment delimiters? can it be run from any editor using `arara`? I ask this out of honest curiousity. All of the things I have just listed are features of `latexindent.pl`

Comment: @cmhughes of course yes, AUCTeX knows about verbatim environments, it doesn't indent them.  To align tabular-like environments there is the [`align-current`](http://babbagefiles.blogspot.it/2011/01/latex-table-manipulation-using.html) function.

Comment: @giordano good to know. It's still specific to one editor though